# Does delve support hot swapping of changes or some variant?

Tags: go, hotswap, delve

Delve is an amazing debugger. Does delve support hot swapping of changes or something similar like the java jvm? It takes me a lot of time to copy my code into docker's build vm, then build all the files, then build & deploy dlv, then copy all the binaries to the runtime docker container. I am looking to speed up my flow. So, I was wondering if hot swap will ever be supported?

Comment: Question regarding what will happen in the future are hard to answer.

Comment: Questions about what the delve developers might do, are best directed toward the delve developers.

Comment: The community can't possibly guess what the developers of any program or library might or might not one day do. However, it seems unlikely that Delve would add this since Go is a static compiled language, unlike Java bytecode which can be modified in memory at runtime.

Comment: I removed the future-prediction part of the question, which is, for obvious reasons, off-topic, leaving the part about current support.

Answer (score 2):

> Does delve support hot swapping of changes

No. Because Go does not support this, because Go is statically compiled, meaning that the output is a single, autonomous executable file. It's not possible to hot-swap parts of a statically compiled binary.

Fortunately, Go is highly optimized for fast compilation times. When properly configured, even the most complex Go programs can compile in seconds or less, when small changes are made, due to the way unaltered bits can be cached, and require no re-compilation.

This should provide most or all of the benefit (to debugging) that hot-swapping would, without the added complexity.

Comment: It is possible according to https://github.com/go-delve/delve/issues/1554 but won't be implemented anytime soon.

Comment: I'd say it's an overstatement to say that it's "possible" according to that link. That link says it's not _impossible_. Few things are literally impossible, with open-source software. But it also essentially confirms my answer here.